# Лучший способ отладки модулей WPF. Получить/Создать не оптимизированную версию сборок

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, отладка, assembly

Можно ли где-то/как-то получить неоптимизированную версию .Net WPF сборок. Так что отладчик в Visual Studio будет подсвечивать значение всех переменных и позиция строки отладчика будет точно совпадать с позицией исходника.

У меня есть компоненты для WPF которые медленно работают. Но понять причину медленной работы довольно трудно, так как при серверной отладке Net Framework сборок, используются оптимизированные сборки без отладочной информации.

Кто-нибудь решал подобную проблему?

Можно взять исходники .NET Framework отсюда
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/
но они не компилируются.

Можно также взять исходники WPF из github,
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf
но его также не удаются скомпилировать чтобы получить отладочную версию сборок.

Comment: Есть хардкорный [WinDbg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools), он даже нейтив код отлаживать умеет, он сложный, но и мощный, даже дедлоки в автоматическом режиме ловит. В общем, вам стоит на него взглянуть.

Comment: На такой низкий уровень мне опускаться не надо.
Но Visual Studio не показывает значение переменных и часто полей при отладке оптимизированных сборок, и часто движется по некорректным строчкам кода, что сильно усложняет понимание работы кода.
Сомневаюсь, что другие отладчики смогут показать больше чем информации о коде чем Visual Studio если в отладочном файле просто нет информации о переменных.

Comment: я бы начал с профайлера и понимания что конкретно и где тормозит

Comment: Этап с профайлером уже пройден.
Тормозит ArrangeOverride Custom панели, на которой много Child элементом.
При скроллинге, по логике, ArrangeOverride панели должен вызываться один раз,
но в каких-то случаях он начинает вызываться бесконтрольно много раз.
Похоже, кто-то начинает активно выставлять признак UIElement.ArrangeDirty у большого числа элементов.
Но т.к. PresentationCore.dll оптимизирован, его трудно отлаживать.

Comment: когда я последние 2 раза встречался с подобной проблемой, в первом случае пришлось писать свою VirtualPanel, во втором случае помогла встроенная виртуализация. Если у вашего UI много чилдов, я бы изначально задумался - а надо ли проекту столько чилдов, в чем смысл этого? Можно ли убрать всю панельку с кастомным кодом и переписать на стандартных контролах?